# Why are there no spaces showing between paragraphs?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

No matter how many spaces I enter in Pages between paragraphs, they do not show on the actual website after I hit update. Why is that?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by spaces? Line breaks or just spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress remove the line breaks by default.

If you need yo add more line breaks you can either disallow Wordpress to do it in the options.

You can either add `<br />` where you need to add line breaks in the **HTML editor**.
You need to add as much as line break you need. One `<br />` is one line break.

Or use a plugin which stop the line breaks removing like **Tiny MCE Advanced** available here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

Then you will have to activate `the option stop removing <p> and <br>` in the plugin settings.

Comment: Hi @Shipo I don't want to use tags ,How to do in Wordpress ? Thanks for replying me Please help

Comment: Still not working ,I installed tinymce-advanced and also enabled stop removing </br> ,</p> tags